# How to address OpenID providers downtime?

Tags: openid

OpenID is all good... UNTIL the provider goes down.  At that point you're potentially locked out of EVERYTHING (since you jumped on the bandwagon and applied OpenID everywhere you could).

*This question came up because I can't, for the life of me, login with my **myopenid.com** provider. :-(*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The fix is for your OpenID site to accept multiple OpenIDs per user account. Something that the spec recommends.

Comment: Instead of "your OpenID site" It would be clearer to say "the site accepting your OpenID (commonly known as an OpenID consumer)". One of the highest voted suggestions on uservoice is for stackoverflow to allow people to change the associated OpenID.

Comment: Being able to change your OpenID though would not solve the problem of your OpenID provider being down though, as you'd not be able to login to change it.

Comment: @Ollie - setting up multiple *in advance* would work just fine.

Comment: I need it now since I can't get through on myopenid.com

Comment: Update: stackoverflow now allows you to change your openid and add an alternate.

Answer (score 6):

This is why I use my personal website to delegate OpenID services to another site.  If WordPress.com (my current chosen provider) goes down, I just switch the code in my site to point at a different provider. A few seconds and I'm back up and running.

Comment: If your website goes down, then you are still screwed.

Comment: I don't think this makes sense, would the alternate provider have the users' information? I don't know how it works too well but that seems to be wrong

Comment: Milhous - it's far more under my control that way, though. If I need to, I can point my DNS at a friend's server and put up a barebones HTML page with the OpenID code.  There are very few ways my site is going to go down for more than 15 minutes or so (other than forgetting to renew the domain).

Comment: George Mauer - that's not how OpenID works. Data isn't stored at the OpenID provider, just your account credentials. Data is stored on the site - StackOverflow stores its own data, but it associates that data with my OpenID URL.  As long as I control ceejayoz.com, I can use OpenID.

Comment: [continued] I already have lots of OpenIDs - AIM, Yahoo!, WordPress.com, etc.  If WordPress.com goes down, I can point my delegation at AIM instead, log in with my AIM credentials, and have the same access and data I had before, pretty much seamlessly.

Comment: It is a partial solution, but still, if your webserver goes down, and you can't control the domain by some reason, you're still screwed. Being able to register multiple OpenIDs on the other hand always works.

Comment: The chances of my (very reliable) domain registrar and my (very reliable) webhost both going down at the same time strikes me as not worth worrying about.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is simple.  Store an email for the user.  Have your own login mechanism.  Making OpenId optional is the straight forward answer to this.

Unfortunately some sites are closed minded about OpenId.